# Is a static member function defined inside a class implicitly inlined?

Tags: c++, function, static, inline

As far as I know, every non-static member function defined inside a class is implicitly inlined. 
Now I am wondering if the same is valid for static member functions, considering that I can define the function multiple times in different translation units.

As an example:

```
class Foo {

public:

    static void static_f(void) { std::cout << static_data << std::endl; } //Is it inline?
    static void static_f2(void); //I guess it isn't

private:

    static int static_data;
    int non_static_data;
};
```

PS: In this document (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf) I found this lines:

> 9.4.1 Static member functions [class.static.mfct] 1 [ Note: The rules described in 9.3 apply to static member functions. — end note ]

and previously in Section 9.3:

> A member function may be defined (8.4) in its class definition, in
>   which case it is an inline member function (7.1.2) [...]

Comment: Yes, but if you're worried about it, throwing in the `inline` keyword won't hurt anything.

Comment: The function will be `inline` which does not meant that it will be *inlined*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Yes.**

I would quote the standard, but you already did.

> considering that I can define the function multiple times in different translation units.

Only if you guarantee that the contents will be the same, making this a non-issue.

Be sure not to conflate "declaration" and "definition" — only when you provide the function body right there inside the class definition does any of this apply. That also makes your worry a non-issue.

```
// "Is it inline?"      YES.
static void static_f(void) { std::cout << static_data << std::endl; }

// "I guess it isn't"   Nope.
static void static_f2(void);
```

Finally, be aware that these functions will be implicitly marked `inline`, but this is not the same thing as actually being *inlined*.

Comment: +1. Note though that `static` or non-static, all member-functions are inline if they're defined inside the class itself.